# How can I sync Google Calendar to my tablet with Android 4.0.3?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync, calendar, google-calendar

I have tablet (Android 4.0.3) with "Android ICS calendar" and I want to synchronize it with my google account.

In "Accounts and synchronization" menu I have my google account, but in details i can only choose synchronization for Books, Gmail, Google Reader, Internet and Contacts.

Do I have to install some other tool?

EDIT:
Ok, Currently I have:

- Android ICS calendar 4.0.3-eng.root.20120523.181717
- Android ICS calendar 4.0.3
- Business Calendar Free 1.1.9.8free
- Jorte 1.4.6
- Checkmark Callendar 2.4

And like @Christian wrote first one (first two) are unsupported by google. So which one is supported - i mean which on i have to install to get sync option in "Accounts and synchronization" menu?

Comment: Do you have a calendar app in the drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded ugly workaround ([link](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/336029-how-do-you-configure-gmail-exchange-activesync.html#post2687835)).

Add exchange account:

```
domain\username: is my aspmx.l.google.com\username@gmail.com
server: m.google.com
```

Now I can sync calendar - but only first one :/.

Still looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) official app, available for devices running Android 4.0.3 and later.

[image: Tablet with Google Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this app, [Android 4 ICS Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.calendar)?

If so, it's probably unsupported by Google Sync. Wasn't there any calendar app preinstalled on your tablet?

Comment: He didn't mention any apps?

Comment: Yes he did, "Android ICS calendar".

Comment: I meant third party ones, not preinstalled

Comment: Yes. This one was preinstalled. But i was able to install another version of this app. So now I have two versions: "4.0.3-eng.root.20120523.181717" and "4.0.3". But as I see any this app (and few others too that I tried) uses account defined in "Accounts and synchronization", and there a can't choose calendar sync.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if you have a gmail account.

Comment: The OP says he can sychronize Gmail so I think he does have a Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the Google Calendar app for your android default app can sync with your online gmail account.

Comment: The Google Calendar app cannot be downloaded, it's already integrated into the default app (as a calendar provider).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/android-tablet-discussions/23013-solved-exchange-account-puzzle.html

Basically you use your gmail user name and password & when it asks for your server information use m.google.com.